# ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got ARRAY

Tags: php, oracle, types, ora-00932

I am trying to fetch an array through PHP but I am receiving the error below:

```
" Warning: oci_fetch_array(): ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: 
 expected CHAR got ARRAY in  test.php".
```

I expect the VARRAY column to be made available in my program using any available collection methods. The query runs fine with Toad but not with PHP.

```
Query : SELECT myfunarr(array_of_varchar('a', 'b')) FROM DUAL
```

Here `array_of_varchar` is my collection of VARRAY.

Any hint to resolve this issue ?

Comment: try to find out output of `myfunarr(array_of_varchar('a', 'b'))` in php first an then pass it to the query in php.

Comment: Can you post your PHP script and the definition of the `myfunarr` function?

Answer (score 0):

- Make a function which gets value of `myfunarr(array_of_varchar('a', 'b'))` as input and generates query string on the basis of its value
- Return this query string through function
- Use this returned query for SQL execution through PHP

**Eg.**

Parameter is `$tab_name` passed in function createQuery($tab_name)

Query made using this: `"Select $tab_name from dual"`

Return this query and have in `$query = createQuery(myfunarr(array_of_varchar('a', 'b')));`

Execute this `$query`